# Extend report for karate with Junit5

Tags: hook, karate, junit5

I want to implement the extend report to karate , I need the extensionhook class that no longer exists in karate-junit5
Any idea how can do that with karate and junit 5 ?
my pom.xml is as follow

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4</version>
        </dependency>`
```

Thank you in advance